# How to access Model in Controller in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to call model methods from controller. but I am getting Fatal error: Class 'GuestModel' not found in.  error

following is the code ::

Controller ::

```
class GuestController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {

     public function indexAction(){
        $guestbook = new GuestModel();
        $this->view->entries = $guestbook->fetchAll();
     }
 }
```

Model::

```
class GuestModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
 {
 public function fetchAll()
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();
        $entries   = array();
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $entry = new Application_Model_Guestbook();
            $entry->setId($row->id)
                  ->setEmail($row->email)
                  ->setComment($row->comment)
                  ->setCreated($row->created);
            $entries[] = $entry;
        }
        return $entries;
    }


    public function getDbTable()
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Guestbook');
        }
        return $this->_dbTable;
    }


 public function setDbTable($dbTable)
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }
        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }
        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;
        return $this;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend Framework autoload depends on using the correct directory structure and file naming conventions to find the classes *automagically*, from the looks of your code my guess would be you're not following it.

I see 2 possible solutions for your problem:

1. If possible, rename your class to **Application_Model_Guestbook**, the file to **Guestbook.php** and make sure to move it to your **application/models/** directory. Then you just need to call it in your controller as **$guestbook = new Application_Model_Guestbook();**. Check this [documentation example](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html);
2. Create your own additional autoloading rules. Check the official documentation regarding [Resource Autoloading](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.autoloading.resources.html).